# Is having a mostly-unavailable name server in SOA or NS RRs for a zone harmful?

Tags: domain-name-system

We typically run with two nameservers, `ns1` and `ns2` as a master-slave, for the domains we serve. We have some planned maintenance coming up that could affect one or both of those, so we're planning to add an `ns3` hosted elsewhere.

We'd have to add `ns3` to the origins of all the domains we serve. However, we don't necessarily need to keep `ns3` running all the time.

Is there any harm in having a nameserver in your SOA/NS which is mostly unavailable? Will it result in some nameservers believing a domain is down, or taking longer to find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a name server is named in the delegation, it is a candidate for selection by a resolver. If you have three name servers named in the delegation, then we can expect each one to get about 1/3 of the traffic, assuming that all three are online.

If one of those are offline, that's 1/3 of the traffic which has to:

1. be recognized as not being answered by the server it was directed at, and
2. be resent to a different server

That process is going to slow down name resolution, because #1 must complete before #2 can happen.

Resolvers will usually recognize after a while that a name server is not responding, and may very well throttle queries to it in response. By doing so, it will only get probed occasionally. This, and how those resolvers respond when it is detected as coming back online, is strictly speaking implementation details of the resolvers. Simple resolvers might just keep trying for every query.

**Naming in the delegation a name server which you know will be mostly offline is counterproductive at best, and user-hostile at worst.**

**A better approach,** assuming that you can't go with something like a multicast IP for your authoritative DNS, would probably be to reduce the TTLs on your authoritative `ns1` and `ns2` A and AAAA RRs, and change the IP addresses on those RRs on an as-needed basis to direct traffic to where you want it to go. Remember to do the same with the corresponding PTR RRs, especially if these servers provide any other services. (DNS is largely insensitive to forward/reverse name mapping correspondence, but other services can be *very* picky. Tread accordingly.) The first name resolution for each resolver may still be slow (because it might pick up an old IP address from the delegation records) but that situation should resolve itself as soon as it gets an authoritative response with the updated IP addresses.

Comment: I've taken this on board. A supplementary question related to your suggestion: what happens if you have more than on A or AAAA record for a nameserver's domain? ie, if ns1.example.com corresponded to two or more IP addresses?

Comment: @MarcusDowning I suspect, but we are likely in the realm of implementation details rather than protocol-mandated behavior, that the different IP addresses listed would be treated as different name servers, subject to any applicable preference settings (including subnet metric and IPv4/IPv6 preference) on the resolver. By the way, proper nomenclature is *host*, not *domain*. "Domain" loosely means what DNS refers to as *zones*, which are deliminated by SOA RRs.